# How to prerender a "*" (not-found) page in VUE using spa-prerender plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [spa-prerender-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) in Vue.js and everything works fine.

However, I would like to pre-render my 404 page as well which in Vue goes like:

```js
{ 
    path: '*', 
    name: 'FourOhFour', 
    component: FourOhFour 
}
```

Using the plugin, I would like to add the 404 as such:

```js
routes: ['/', '/contact', '*'],
```

But on trying this, I get:

> ERROR in [prerender-spa-plugin] Unable to prerender all routes!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another simple solution **without** editing .htaccess file.
Just insert statement for prerendering to your router:

```
{
      path: '/404',
      name: 'FourOhFour',
      component: FourOhFour
  },
  {
      path: '*',
      name: 'FourOhFourX',
      component: FourOhFour
  }
```

and prerender static route:

```
routes: ['/', '/contact', '/404'],
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin/issues/237 this is not possible.

You can edit your router code like

```
path: '/404', 
name: 'FourOhFour', 
component: FourOhFour
```

and redirect unresloved routes to 404 page in .htaccess by replacing this line

```
RewriteRule    (.*) index.html [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule    (.*) 404/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi @bazilisok. Yeah I opened the issue on his GitHub repo and his response made me take another route. Apparently, I still needed the url to carry the intended url, whilst showing the 404 page. Not to redirect to another `/404` page entirely. I'm currently using Node.js wildcard as a temp-fix to display a 404 page and still hold on to the intended URL. (Downside is that it redirects to homepage first, but it works).

Comment: I understand, but in my example browser keeps intended URL, and shows only 404 page content as you demand. At least in my current project, that I'm working on.

Comment: Yours too should work :) Though I can't test it as my app is on Heroku and node.js is a safer way to go. But I'll do that soon and give your +1 when tested.